# return a list as a unique list using tuples

Tags: python

The job is to return a list back as a unique list. However my code doesn't work correctly.

```
def unique_list(lst):
    d=(lst)
    print(d)
```

When I enter `unique_list([1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,5])`, it returns the same thing. But when I do print(d) on a new cell, it returns the unique numbers. I'm just confused why.

Comment: it is not clear what you want to achieve, can you be more specific what you mean by "unique list"?

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf presumably no duplicate characters. Try seeing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961363/removing-duplicates-in-lists

Comment: What do you mean "when I use print(d) on a new cell"? What is a "new cell"? When you wrap something in parentheses, you're just making it a tuple. This should in now way remove duplicate items. You may be confusing it with `set()` which DOES return only unique items

Comment: @Aaewatech, it would be nice if you can provide an example of the input and the output you want to get.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing duplicates in lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961363/removing-duplicates-in-lists)

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure this is what you are looking for:

```
example = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5]

def unique_list(list_):
    return list(set(list_))

print(unique_list(example))
```